# Habilitar TSL 1.0 e 1.1 NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, nginx-config

Minha API está habilitado para uso de TSL 1.2 e 1.3, porém temos uma demanda para consumo dela de uso de TSL 1.0.

Utilizo NGINX e Certbot let's encrypt para certificação.

Já fiz vários teste de ssl_ciphers possíveis também.

NGINX:

```
server {
  gzip on;

  root /var/www/sistema/frontend/dist/;
  server_name api.sistema.com.br;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.sistema.com.br/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.sistema.com.br/privkey.pem;
}
```

/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf

```
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
```

Erro ao tentar conectar openssl s_client -connect api.sistema.com.br:443 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
140504499033408:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 70

ssl_ciphers que já tentei:
'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH'
'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
'AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-SHA'